# fill a space with text

Tags: php, javascript, jquery, html, css

I am trying to adjust text size so it can fill a certain space

For example :
so, lets say that my HTML is like this :

```
<h1 style="width:120px;">some text</h1>
```

I want the word "some text" to fill the 120px automatically knowing that "some text" could be anything! I do not care if the font width is stretched or some spaces has been added to the word to make it fit the 120px width.

I know that in CSS we have `overflow:hidden;` and `overflow:scroll;` but those two will not help me with anything

`overflow:hidden;` will hide any extra characters outside the 120px
`overflow:scroll;` will make a scroll which I do not want !

any solutions? maybe a Jquery plugin or something? I have looked everywhere but I could not find anything.

Comment: try `width:100%` on the text element

Comment: Do you want your text to extend to other lines or do you want it to be always on one line ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You may adapt the font to the available space using such a script :

```
var fontSize = 100;
var reduce = function() {
    $('#txt').css('font-size', fontSize);
    $('#mes').html(fontSize);
    if ($('#txt').width()>MAX_MIDTH) {
       fontSize -= 1;
        reduce();
    }
};
reduce();
$('#width, #height').change(function(){fontSize = 100;reduce()});
```

[Demonstration](http://jsfiddle.net/kPZ3E/)

Comment: Yes, for [a question a little similar](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13416673/javascript-convert-width-and-height-to-font-size) (I'm trying to see if this one can be said to be a duplicate).

Answer (score 1):

Align your text using `text-align: justify`

Comment: what if I have a long name that needs more than 120px

Comment: Why not checking? It will be broken into multi line text.

Comment: I only want the test to be on one line